# Connect Fb through curl in php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

i need to get user feeds from Facebook using curl , i have send request through curl and got

```
Facebook returned HTTP Error Code: 404 error, follow is my code to connect facebook through curl 
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "php-facebook-wall (https://github.com/dordotky/php-facebook-wall)");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".FACEBOOK_USER_NAME
    ."/".FACEBOOK_USER_OBJECT."?access_token=".FACEBOOK_APP_ID."|".FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);

// Execute our curl request
$result = curl_exec($curl);

// Check that we didn't encounter any errors while processing
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ((!curl_error($curl)) && ($http_code == 200))
{
    $json = json_decode($result, true);
} else
{
    die("Facebook returned HTTP Error Code: ".$http_code);
}
?>
```

Comment: can you give me your access token? you want to post something on facebook wall? & yes first check SSL enabled in your server...

Comment: curl need to enable SSL? i need to get feeds from FB not to post on FB

Comment: Yes, curl need SSL enable & check your access token because its changed every times.

Comment: get it your answer or not?

Comment: not working , actually curl don't need of SSL enabled, other CURL functions returns in my server.

Comment: you want to use for your website or web service?

Comment: on my website, i need to get user timeline using their user name need to show them in their dashboard.

Comment: Open ‘php.ini’ and replace:
;extension=php_curl.dll
with
extension=php_curl.dll

Comment: there is no issue with curl in my server, other curl functions is working fine in my server

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25601/discussion-between-advait-amin-and-jothikannan)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this example of post image on Facebook wall.
Steps to take care:

1. SSL enabled on your server.
2. Access Token changed after some times so use latest access token.

   function facebook_upload($fb_oauth_token,$item_image)
   {

   ```
   $file = $item_image;

       $args = array(
           'access_token'=>urlencode($fb_oauth_token)
       );

       $args[basename($file)] = '@'.($file);

       $ch = curl_init();
       $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos';
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
       $data = curl_exec($ch);
       //returns the photo id
       $response = json_decode($data,true);
       //print_r(curl_error($ch));

       //to check response
       //if($response[id]>0){
           // yes
       //}
       json_decode($data,true);
   ```

   }